# lenovo g710 usb not working

Tags: usb

I have an issue with my USB ports, all ports have power but are not working.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  

$ lsusb -v
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x8000 
  bcdDevice            0.05
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0002  1x 2 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             8
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        0 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.04
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.4.0-12-generic ehci_hcd
  iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0507 highspeed power suspend enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x8008 
  bcdDevice            0.05
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood        0 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.04
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.4.0-12-generic ehci_hcd
  iProduct                2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1a.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x02
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0507 highspeed power suspend enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.04
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.4.0-12-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x18
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         512 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.04
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.4.0-12-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts            14
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0xb2 0x7f
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
   Port 9: 0000.0100 power
   Port 10: 0000.0100 power
   Port 11: 0000.0100 power
   Port 12: 0000.0100 power
   Port 13: 0000.0100 power
   Port 14: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'usb'
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.237106] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.237106] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.237106] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.290886] pci 0000:00:1a.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x662 took 22185 usecs
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.314880] pci 0000:00:1d.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x662 took 23416 usecs
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.462996] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.462998] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.463000] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.463001] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-12-generic ehci_hcd
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.463002] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.482894] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.482896] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.482897] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.482898] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-12-generic ehci_hcd
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.482899] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.484679] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.484680] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.484681] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.484682] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-12-generic xhci-hcd
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.484683] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.487904] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.487905] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.487906] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.487907] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-12-generic xhci-hcd
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.487908] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.802842] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.818828] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.959266] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008, bcdDevice= 0.05
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.959268] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.975408] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000, bcdDevice= 0.05
Feb 13 07:45:48 janjula-Lenovo-G710 kernel: [    0.975410] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please shut down the system. Then, with a LiveUSB (perhaps generated on another PC), are you able to power up, choose the Boot Manager, and boot from the LiveUSB? If not, it's a BIOS problem or hardware failure.

Comment: Ty... Didnt think of it.... Very simple to try... What a dumb i feel for not thinking of it....    

Comment: The general high quality of Lenovo numbs me as well. I am shocked when something fails on a ThinkBox.

Comment: It seems like it doesnt recognise nothing.... but it has power to charge a phone.... So i guess nothing to be done here... Usb ports gone... Will try to find an old firmware to see if it works with older...